# How can I initialize a color array that shows color cubes in Swift 3?

Tags: xcode

I found this code part on GitHub and it works really fine, I can even change the color by clicking on the color cube. Also, I could copy the color cube and use anywhere I wanted. I want to know how to initialize this in Swift 3.

[image: color cubes in code]

I tried this but couldn't figure it out.

```
    let cc = [UIColor(red: CGFloat(160/255), green: CGFloat(183.0/255), blue: CGFloat(227.0/255), alpha: 1), UIColor(red: CGFloat(160/255), green: CGFloat(183.0/255), blue: CGFloat(227.0/255), alpha: 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **color literals** in order to achieve this.

```
#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

In fact, you shouldn't even memorize this, as the autocompletion will show a Color Literal option to you if you start typing it in.

[image: Color Literal autocompletion]

After that, **double-click** on the appearing square and you can pick from colors there:

[image: color picker popover]

Clicking on **Other...** reveals the standard color picker of macOS:

[image: the standard color picker of macOS]

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating color literals in one of your model files, do not forget import UIKit before you do this.